# Get Android category information of a running task

Tags: android, android-activity, task, categories

In Android, I can get the running tasks and activities using code like tis:

```
(ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo) this.mActivityManager.getRunningTasks()
```

Then I can get the package name, class name etc.

My question is that whether there is a way to get the "category" information from it? Or anyone can suggest an alternative solution? for example, when I launch an app, the category is

```
cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
```

Comment: No response? If it is a stupid questions, please also kindly let me know. :)

Comment: Sorry, my original post might not be clear. So in my application, I want to check the list of running tasks with a filter of certain category. For example, I would like get list of running tasks that in the cat  [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] to get a list of activities that was launched by the launcher. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: Well, I guess that there is no way to get a list of activities launched by the launcher?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you mean, but maybe the following is what you want: retrieve the intent in your activity by calling `getIntent()`, and on the Intent object call the method `getCategories()`. This method will return a set with category strings.

Comment: Thanks. but I am not trying to get categories for my own activity, but all running activities in the system. I added some clarification as comment.

Comment: Ok, the comment clarifies your question. However, I don't know how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, whether this would solve your problem, but you may use [ActivityManager's getRecentTasks(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29)  API to get information about the recent tasks. It returns a list of [ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo.html) objects, which have information about the intent used to launch the task. You can also use `RecentTaskInfo.id` field to map the task with the running tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I found no direct way of doing it, but this may help:

```
Intent ApplicationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
ApplicationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);  

List<ResolveInfo> LauncherResolves = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(ApplicationIntent, 0);

List<String> AppsList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < LauncherResolves.size(); i++)
    AppsList.add(LauncherResolves.get(i).activityInfo.name);

List<RunningTaskInfo> runningAppInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(10);
for (int i = 0; i < runningAppInfo.size(); i++)
{
    if (AppsList.contains(runningAppInfo.get(i).topActivity.getClassName()))
    {
        // Do what ever you want
    }
}
```